# Is there any way to extract data from text file in Excel through python?

Tags: python-3.x, oracle, xlrd, xlwt

Iam new to Python so completing my task is always a big hassle for me. I do try a lot of things but generally get stuck .So I hope that someone could assist me.

There is one procedure with humungous line of code . I want to make table out of it that I can use for my further coding  .

```
--Product1--
begin
     insert into   crs_daily_production_data select :I_DT,3,3,21,'A01',
     NVL(A1_506,0),NVL(A1_507,0),NVL(A1_508,0) FROM DAILYTECH_OUTPUT
     WHERE DATA_DATE=:I_DT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    
    SELECT NVL(A1_506,0),NVL(A1_507,0),NVL(A1_508,0) INTO V_PROD,V_MPROD,V_YPROD
    FROM DAILYTECH_OUTPUT
     WHERE DATA_DATE=:I_DT;
     
     UPDATE   crs_daily_production_data SET 
     DAILY_QTY=V_PROD,CUM_MONTHLY_QTY=V_MPROD,CUM_YEARLY_QTY=V_YPROD
     WHERE DT=:I_DT AND UNIT_CD=3 AND PLANT_CD=3 AND PRODUCT_CD='A01' AND STREAM_CD=21;  
     END ;


--Product2
begin
    V_PROD:=0;V_MPROD:=0;V_YPROD:=0;
     insert into   crs_daily_production_data select :I_DT,3,702,21,'A02',
     NVL(A2_506,0),NVL(A2_507,0),NVL(A2_508,0) FROM DAILYTECH_OUTPUT
     WHERE DATA_DATE=:I_DT;
EXCEPTION
    WHEN DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX THEN
    
    SELECT NVL(A2_506,0),NVL(A2_507,0),NVL(A2_508,0) INTO V_PROD,V_MPROD,V_YPROD
    FROM DAILYTECH_OUTPUT
     WHERE DATA_DATE=:I_DT;
     
     UPDATE   crs_daily_production_data SET 
     DAILY_QTY=V_PROD,CUM_MONTHLY_QTY=V_MPROD,CUM_YEARLY_QTY=V_YPROD
     WHERE DT=:I_DT AND UNIT_CD=3 AND PLANT_CD=702 AND PRODUCT_CD='A02' AND STREAM_CD=21;
     
     END ;
```

Above Code is example of 2 product where with some condition, data is saved into pre defined table.
I want to make new table and it should have columns like(all these data is available in the TXT file)
**Product // Data Table// Column Name (i.e. A1_506) // Data table(if value available)//Plant Code/Unit Code//StreamCode etc** where I can use this table in loop and optimize that procedure in for future working.

Is there any way I can do this efficiently as I don't want to copy paste data for 4k rows manually.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, be more focused: you've tagged Python and Excel, but post *some* Oracle code and ask for assistance without specific requirements.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I think there is some confusion about what and how I was trying to do
1. Procedure is extracted in Text file and I want python to read it ,so it is just a simple text now.
2. After reading text I want to make a new excel with the column name mentioned above and all these column data is available in that text file
3. Above is the sample of text that have multiple products and it goes all the way to 4k line which I want to avoid